# Swift Combine HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, http, combine

Trying to figure out how to make quick http requests using combine. I've mostly been looking at this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/processing_url_session_data_task_results_with_combine) by Apple. I haven't made any progress though and it seems simple enough so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm use to JavaScript and using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
Also use to [http pkg](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) in Golang
But for some reason doing it in Swift is really confusing to me like it's not very streamlined like the two I mentioned

I'm using SwiftUI with the MVVM architecture so my goal is to implement a way of communicating to my Golang server in my view model.

This requires mostly `POST` requests with `Accept` and `Authorization` headers and a `JSON` body

I tried this code:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://api.example.com/user/login")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue(String(format: "Bearer %s", idToken!), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
_ = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .tryMap() { element -> Data in
        // not worried about the status code just trying to get any response.
        guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode >= 200
        else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        return element.data
    }
    // .decode(type: LoginResponseData.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()) commenting this out because I just want to see any data.
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print ("Received completion: \($0).") },
        receiveValue: { data in print ("Received user: \(data).")}
    )
```

And get this console message: `nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed`
Which I read [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-firebase-connection/41632/2) may have nothing to do with my issue however they were talking about firebase I think.

I would like to know if there is anything wrong with my code?
Or a working example with some `JSON` API or even a http `GET` request of some website would be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not set `_` to the pipeline. Make the pipeline and add `store(in:)` at the end and store it. Otherwise nothing will happen. Many simple examples in my online tutorial: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/start/startpipelines.html

Comment: @matt Wouldn't the two `print` statements log something still, even without `store(in:)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's make a very rudimentary reduction of your code:

```
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")!)
    _ = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in print("completion")},
              receiveValue: { print($0) })
```

Result: *Nothing prints at all*.

---

Okay, now let's do what I suggested in my comment. We have an instance property:

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
```

And we change the code to look like this:

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in print("completion")},
              receiveValue: { print($0) })
        .store(in:&self.storage)
```

And we get this in the console (well, at least I do):

```
(data: 74909 bytes, response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600002e479e0> { URL: https://www.apple.com/ } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "max-age=151"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        10974
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 04 Dec 2020 17:45:50 GMT"
    );
    Expires =     (
        "Fri, 04 Dec 2020 17:48:21 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
    "Set-Cookie" =     (
        "geo=US; path=/; domain=.apple.com",
        "ccl=uQisGvuhtgEjEZERqJarcpJqZcmsz2JEaxjveIr8V14=; path=/; domain=.apple.com"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding"
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} })
completion
```

---

To understand the difference, perhaps it will help to think about Heraclitus. "You can't step in the same river twice, because different and different waters keep flowing." That river is *time*.

- In *your* code, the publisher-to-sink pipeline is created *and thrown away* — because it is purely local to this method, which creates the pipeline and instantly ends. Meanwhile, the river is flowing! So the pipeline is gone *before the request even had a chance to get started*. It never starts so it never finishes. It never finishes so it never prints.
- In *my* code, the publisher-to-sink pipeline is *preserved* (in an instance property). That is what `store` does. Thus the request has a chance to start, and still later it has a chance to finish, long after the pipeline was created, while the river keeps flowing and flowing.

Comment: I was able to get this to work with my own implementation. I will take this, read your website, and hopefully this will lead me to really start understanding this. Thank you!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. It really helped me because of the combo
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
.store(in:&self.storage)
I was only having one reference -> ex: var published: AnyCancellable = URLSession...etc, which made that if I had multiple requests, only the last one would keep its reference and thereby it would be the only one that I had a response...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hoping can help someone:

I did paste by error:

```
@State var cancellableUploadTask: AnyCancellable?
```

instead of:

```
private var cancellableUploadTask: AnyCancellable?
```

and it failed...